# How to Control the image's position inside shape in drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

In android studio I created xml drawable, it's rectangle divided to 3 child rectangles .
[image: like in this]
I want to insert an image in the 3rd part Which is equal to 25% of the total area.
How to make the inserted image position in the 75% part (the third part) ?

I asked chatGPT and it generate this code :

```
<item android:left="75%"

    android:top="0dp"

    android:right="0dp"

    android:bottom="0dp">
```

I got unknown unit '%' error

Comment: What use case are you trying to achieve? Why do you want an image inside a drawable? Do you want three images side by side with border?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want three images side-by-side with border you can instead use `LinearLayout` containing three `ImageView` and control their width using `weight` property.

Here is sample code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the drawable border's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

Here is the sample output:

[image: Sample Output]